# PDO - Return all rows where date column equals this month, however date is formatted as unix timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm experimenting with a PDO connection to MySQL in PHP.

```
$thismonth = date('Ym');
print ($thismonth);
```

= **201502**

I want to fetch all rows where the timestamp column (which contains unix timestamp) equals the above string (after some sort of on the fly conversion), or perhaps another way that will return current month.

```
try {
    $sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, domain, date FROM `domains` WHERE `date` = :thismonth ');
    $sql->bindParam(':thismonth', $thismonth);
    $sql->execute();
    $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $conn = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "\n" . "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        die();
    }
    var_dump($results);
```

I know the above is not going to work. And could be horribly wrong.
Can the :thismonth parameter be an on the fly comparison? Any assistance being pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lookup the documentation for the MySQL date/time functions and bookmark that because its very useful:

```
.... where MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`)) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: I don’t think `MONTH` will work when the column contains a unix timestamp; `FROM_UNIXTIME` using a `format` would be appropriate.

Comment: @CBroe, I thought he was just saying the PHP variable was a unix timestamp. But I'll read the question again.

Comment: @CBroe, Ok, you were right, so I added `FROM_UNIXTIME`

Comment: Thanks guys! I need to read the MYSQL date and time functions. Thanks @CBroe for the additional correction

Comment: Just for clarity, when it rolls around to the same month next year, will it collect the previous years month as well?

Comment: @anastymous, Right. You really need to check both year and month.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `"WHERE date LIKE :thismonth . '%'"`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Ah OK, I've been using Stackoverflow for years looking for answers, only recently created an account to help others. Thanks for pointing out the guidelines! Much appreciated.